# Ember isn't always loading belongsTo

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, rsvp-promise

I can't seem to workout how to load relationships properly in Ember. The user model only returns some of the time. If I refresh the page there seems to be a 50/50 chance the value will be null, or it will resolve correctly.

I understand in the route I'm returning a promise which is the server object (the belongsTo end of the user relationship), but how do I tell the route to wait for the user model to load before loading the page, or how do I tell ember to update the data on the page when it finally does load the user?

I've tried playing around with RSVP in the afterModel hook but haven't had any luck. There must be a obvious solution to this?

**route**

```
model(param) {
  return this.store.findRecord('server', param.server_id);
},
```

**server model**

```
export default Model.extend(Validations, {
  user: belongsTo('user'),
});
```

**user model**

```
export default Model.extend({   
  displayName: attr('string'),
  servers: hasMany('server'),
});
```

**component**

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({});
```

**component template**

```
<div class="user-panel">
    <ul class="user-details">
        <li>owner:{{model.user.displayName}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've read a similar question here [How to load belongsTo/hasMany relationships in route with EmberJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381904/how-to-load-belongsto-hasmany-relationships-in-route-with-emberjs)

But as I'm only returning a single object rather than an array I get `Array Methods must be provided an Array` thrown when trying any of the solutions

**Server response**

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "server",
    "id": "578aba694b08ce2310f36798",
    "attributes": {
      //removed
    },
    "relationships": {
      "jobs": {
        "data": [
          {
            "type": "jobs",
            "id": "578aba694b08ce2310f3679a"
          }
        ]
      },
      "user": {
        "data": {
          "type": "user",
          "id": "57760677d04e0f11f4d3f7e5"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Timing can be finicky with closely related models. If you have control over the API, I'd suggest side-loading the user along with the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work out of the box! Not the waiting part, but the auto update.

Checkout [this](https://ember-twiddle.com/a13fcb066f6387c0f6a77487f0f64892?openFiles=adapters.user.js%2C) twiddle.

But if you want to wait for the model you can just enforce this in the `afterModel` hook:

```
afterModel(model) {
  return get(model, 'user');
}
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I though too, would the fact it's ending up in a nested component have anything to do with it?

Comment: Not really. Only if you don't pass the model through. More likely it's a problem with your API, serializer or adapter. Checkout your state with the ember-inspector. Usual problems are that ember-data thinks it has the record already loaded, or the relationships are not clear.

Comment: Unfortunately the afterModel hook doesn't work. Using inspect I can see the user model ```isFulfilled : true``` but ```content``` is null. The server is returning the user model, and ember is sending the request for the data it just looks like the timing is out and ember isn't updating its record when the data comes back from the server. The server responds correctly every time when using postman to query the endpoint.

Comment: If `isFulfilled:true` and `content:null` then either your server response, your serializer or adapter is doing something wrong! Check it with the ember-inspector. Also check *both* server responses. The `user` and the `server`.

Comment: Im using the 'out the box' serializer (I've not written one) and the default ```JSONAPIAdapter``` with only the host configured. The user response from the server is also correct. The user model has two ```hasMany``` relationships, would I need to declare the inverse in this case?

Comment: Could you provide the response, or better construct a non working twiddle? To fake server delays just use setTimeout.

Comment: Turns out you're correct, my backend wasn't returning the other side of the relationship, so while server returned information about user, user didn't return information about server. Which I didn't know needed to happen. So you're correct in saying it should and it does just work out the box

Comment: Lux : I strugled with problem observing belongsTo changes, observer worked right at some models but worked bad at another models. Problem was that at some cases observer got fired even when no change was made. Then when i checked at debbuger at some cases relation had model with just id (what was expected) but at some times it has content = "null" and when it had "null" observer fired up after relation loaded from ajax even if no change was made. But adding condition to isFulfilled:true into observer resolved problem, tnx very much man ;)